# 2012 Kia Forte Electrical? Power?

Tags: electrical, audio, lights, braking

Audio cuts out when using turn signal or braking.

Lights dim when using turn signal or braking.

Headlights and interior lights have inconsistent brightness. A slow flicker.

After parking and locking vehicle, exterior yellow lights sometimes stay on. Have to start the car again to get them to turn off.

Vehicle frequently does not respond to key fob. Have switched fobs and replaced fob batteries, but the issue persists.

Replaced car battery, but issues persist.

Twice, so far, I’ve turned the key in the ignition and the alarm sounds, but the vehicle will not start. The second time I was able to start with a jump, but when I turned on the headlights all the interior dash lights went completely out.

Computer has been reset twice.

Dealership says they can't duplicate any issue.

Where do I start?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Took it to a local mechanic (not dealership). Alternator replaced and another new battery. So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be more complicated than this, but to answer your question where to start is to clean both ends of both battery cables. Make sure your cables are not corroded. Check that the ground from your battery is good. You need to ensure your vehicle is getting sufficient battery power before moving to the next step.